# How to load a partial view when typing anything after domain name in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

How can I redirect to a particular partial view so that when I typed anything after domain name. I  want to make my URL address only domain name.

Comment: explain your question bye providing url you want to manipulate

Comment: I think you have asked wrong question. if i m not wrong you want to use just domain name  for your mvc application

Comment: my need is when I type http://localhost:53149/Customer/AddCustomer it should remove the url Customer/AddCustomer and redirect to http://localhost:53149  @KaushikThanki

Comment: Then U can use RedirectToAction to your Default Controler's default action 
by this way it will only show the domain